Power MOSFET Simetrix simulation using in LLC
I'm trying to model switching losses of an Infineon Power MOSFET (IAUS300N10S5N014) in SIMetrix/SIMPLIS Elements by using in the LLC circuit. But I have some questions.

In the SIMetrix, how should I drive the MOSFET?
I can put the voltage source to drive the MOSFET when I use SIMPLIS, but in the SIMetrix, I can't do that.

If I want to model switching losses, which level should I use?



If you want to simulate switching losses accurately, you will have to also model the driver with its output impedance and peak current capability.

@VerbalKint Could you please tell me how to do that in the Simetrix? I am a  little confused about  model the driver with its output impedance and peak current

Switching losses are modeled by three MOSFETs, with the power MOSFET having gate capacitance.
First, you have a MOSFET gate driver which is a CMOS inverter. This consists of two MOSFETs. The MOSFETs here should have realistic model parameters that give the right saturation current. This MOSFET gate driver can be driven by the input voltage, i.e. if you put it to zero volts, it gives full output, if you put it to the input voltage, it gives zero volts (it's an inverter after all).
The MOSFET gate driver then drives the power MOSFET and the capacitor in its gate. Be sure to give the capacitor a realistic value. Actually, instead of a single gate capacitor, you might want to use a gate-to-source and a gate-to-drain capacitance as separate elements.
This configuration gives the right characteristic when the MOSFET is turning on and turning off. There's no other way you can model the switching losses when the MOSFET is turning on or turning off. A resistor as a model for a MOSFET gate driver would for example give incorrect results, because MOSFET drivers are more complex than simple resistors, because they consist of MOSFETs too.
Now, I don't know anything about the particular simulation software you want to use, but all of them should use the same way, model the MOSFET driver and the power MOSFET separately.
